# Is it a bad practice to query pg_type for enums on a regular basis?

Tags: postgresql, catalogs, enum

In Postgres, I'm thinking of query `pg_type` for an up-to-date list of enumerations I'm using on a regular basis. I'd be using something like this:

```
SELECT pg_type.typname AS enum_type, pg_enum.enumlabel AS enmu_label FROM 
pg_type JOIN pg_enum ON pg_enum.enumtypid = pg_type.oid;
```

or

```
SELECT distinct pg_type.typname AS enum_type FROM pg_type JOIN pg_enum ON 
pg_enum.enumtypid = pg_type.oid;
```

Is this bad practice?

Comment: The question is why would you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is this bad practice?*

No, not at all, modifying the catalog is bad practice but there is no reason not to query it.

But in your query…

> ```
> SELECT distinct pg_type.typname AS enum_type FROM pg_type JOIN pg_enum ON pg_enum.enumtypid = pg_type.oid;
> ```

…there isn't any need to join `pg_enum` and use `distinct`:

> ```
> create type mood as enum ('sad', 'ok', 'happy');
> ```

> ```
> select * from pg_enum;
> ```
>
> ```
> enumtypid | enumsortorder | enumlabel
> :-------- | :------------ | :--------
> 53430     | 1             | sad      
> 53430     | 2             | ok       
> 53430     | 3             | happy
> ```

> ```
> select typname from pg_type where typtype='e';
> ```
>
> ```
> | typname |
> | :------ |
> | mood    |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=398107a15a2183e2218f6469ca7ddf46)*

Answer (score 5):

What [@Jack said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/198811/3684). Plus, if all you need is the list of registered values for an enum type, there are some [***Enum Support Functions***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-enum.html) to do that. Based on Jack's example:

```
SELECT enum_range(null::mood);

enum_range
--------------
{sad,ok,happy}
```

That's simpler and resilient against (unlikely) changes in future major Postgres versions that might break your query.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=196479aecce5bc6a6aec05dbfb6fa59f)*